# Django, overriding ManyToManyField

Tags: django, many-to-many, overriding

I am sorta building my own widget, based on the ManyToManyRawIdWidget.

But as soon as i try the following in my ModelAdmin:

```
formfield_overrides = {
    ManyToManyField: {'widget': ManyToManyRawIdWidget},
}
```

It'll prompt me

```
__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I figured i needed to fill the `rel` argument with something, probably the relation model (which is a `Tag` model)

But then i run into a TemplateSyntaxError:

```
Caught AttributeError while rendering: type object 'Tag' has no attribute 'to'
```

This is where I lose oversight. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to make sure you heeded this warning in the [documentation for formfield_overrides](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides):

> Warning
>
> If you want to use a custom widget
>   with a relation field (i.e. ForeignKey
>   or ManyToManyField), make sure you
>   haven't included that field's name in
>   raw_id_fields or radio_fields.
>
> formfield_overrides won't let you
>   change the widget on relation fields
>   that have raw_id_fields or
>   radio_fields set. That's because
>   raw_id_fields and radio_fields imply
>   custom widgets of their own.

I'm not aware of the ManyToManyRawIdWidget but judging by its name I assume that raw_id_fields might be set in this case? Which might be why it isn't working.

Comment: No, I came across that warning, and thus thoughtfully removed the field from the raw_id_fields. No luck with that :(